# Execute cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:selector:object: for all objects

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, grand-central-dispatch

I'am scheduling different selectors on different objects

```
[self performSelector:@selector(doSmth) withObject:objectA afterDelay:1];
[self performSelector:@selector(doSmth) withObject:objectB afterDelay:1];
[self performSelector:@selector(doSmthElse) withObject:objectA afterDelay:1];
```

**And i want to cancel all 'doSmth', how to do that?** without knowing the object passed

This will cancel everything

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
```

And this will cancel nothing (as the object doesn't match)

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:object 
    selector:@selector(doSmth) object:nil];
```

Even i would except the behaviour to be (cancel with any object, whe nil is passed, but this doesn't happen)

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to get a list of pending `performSelector` requests, so you'll need to maintain a list of the arguments you're passing to `performSelector` so you can later cancel them.